# Was bedeutet eigentlich "gesäßkalt"?

Tags: swiss-german

Ist *gesäßkalt* (oder in Schweizer Schreibweise *gesässkalt*) eine persönliche Wortschöpfung von Herrn Kachelmann oder gebrauchen auch andere Schweizer Wetterfrösche dieses Wort? Welche Kältegrade beschreibt es?

Übrigens: Der Wetterflash in [meteonews.tv](http://meteonews.tv/Wetter/Schweiz/de) ist meine Lieblingswebsite, um mich in die Schweizer Aussprache einzuhören.

Comment: Klingt wie ein Euphemismus für arschkalt. [Der Spiegel](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/leute/0,1518,811864,00.html) lässt mit dem Begriff "Kachelmannsche Wetterwörter" vermuten, dass diese Wörter nicht sonderlich verbreitet sind.

Comment: Was für musikK Vermutung spricht, dass da jmd im Fernsehen nicht so ein ordinäres Wort aussprechen wollte

Comment: @musiKk: Antworten, nicht kommentieren. Das hier ist eine Frage&Antwort-Seite. A.N.T.W.O.R.T

Comment: @JohnSmithers: Das war nur eine Vermutung mit praktisch null Recherche. Und da mir die Dialekte unserer südlichen Nachbarn nicht geheuer sind, bin ich da besonders vorsichtig. ;)

Comment: @musiKk, Du findest nicht zu allem und jedem eine Referenz im Netz. Manchmal muss man auch ins kalte Gesäßwasser springen. Es gibt hier nicht mehr viele Möglichkeiten. Also antworte. Trau Dich. Es tut nicht weh.

Comment: Wieso falsch ich hatte es aus einer schweizer Quelle.

Comment: Ich wollte es auch erst ohne Umlaut und Esszett schreiben, aber dann dachte ich mir, diese Finsterlinge werden uns hier nicht unserer schönen teutschen Buchstaben berauben. *muhaha*

Comment: Welche Initiative unternommen um die Frage mit eigenen Mitteln (google) zu klären?

Answer (score 16):

*Gesäßkalt* klingt nach einem Euphemismus für *arschkalt*.

Eine kurze Suche nach selbigem Begriff ließ mich auf einen [Artikel des Spiegels](http://www.spiegel.de/panorama/leute/0,1518,811864,00.html) stoßen, welcher Vermuten lässt, dass Jörg Kachelmann sich gerne Begriffe ausdenkt:

> Jörg Kachelmann ist nach knapp zweijähriger Abstinenz zurück auf der Mattscheibe. Mit Wollpullover, selbstgezeichneten DIN-A-4-Blättern und **Kachelmannschen Wetterwörtern**.

(Hervorhebung von mir)

Erwähnte Begriffe sind

- flöckeln
- Angezuckertsein
- das bereits angesprochene gesäßkalt

Zu keinem der Begriffe konnte ich Nennenswertes finden, welches nicht sofort auf Herrn Kachelmann zurückführte.

Die Frage nach dem etwaigen Kältegrad lässt sich vielleicht mit einem [Tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/J_Kachelmann/status/154616821683716097) des Meteorologen beantworten. Demnach bezeichnet er damit wohl Temperaturen um den Gefrierpunkt ±7°C. Recht ungenau also. Vielleicht kann man ihm über Twitter ja mehr entlocken.